# Tensorflow import error: "cudart64_101.dll" not found (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, nvidia

**Hello,**

I have some import problems after the installation of the latest Python Tensorflow release (I want to use it with GPU). It states it couldn't find *"cudart64_101.dll"* which is strange since I have CUDA 10 properly installed and the file can be found on my computer (path: `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\Downloader\PostProcessing\GFE\c15894515e933d7ad026c4344ec1c99d\GFExperience.NvStreamSrv\amd64\server\cudart64_101.dll`). The output is:

```
2020-05-14 17:37:59.997330: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-05-14 17:38:00.001141: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I have tried several suggestions of the internet but none worked for me.

**Detailed system information:**

- Windows 10 Home 64-Bit
- Python 3.6.8 64-Bit for Windows
- Tensorflow v2.2 (CPU and GPU support, installed via `> pip install tensorflow`) installed in virtual environment created with virtualenv (specs: `Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with pre-installed CUDA version 10.1.120
- I don't use Anaconda, so please only suggestions for virtualenv and pip

As I mentioned, I have the file on my computer. Is there a directory I should move it to so Tensorflow can find it? I also searched for this, but that paths aren't on my computer. Should I include something to PATH? Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: No idea what you are referring to, though I do understand the language you chose in this English community. Feel free to link, I appreciate constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

try to install cuda 10.1
hopefully it will create a 'cudart64_101.dll' file
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2